# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil"

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, ffmpeg, javacv

```
public static class AVFormatContext extends Pointer {
    static { Loader.load(); }
    /** Default native constructor. */
    public AVFormatContext() { super((Pointer)null); allocate(); }
    /** Native array allocator. Access with {@link Pointer#position(long)}. */
    public AVFormatContext(long size) { super((Pointer)null); allocateArray(size); }
    /** Pointer cast constructor. Invokes {@link Pointer#Pointer(Pointer)}. */
    public AVFormatContext(Pointer p) { super(p); }
    private native void allocate();
    private native void allocateArray(long size);
    @Override public AVFormatContext position(long position) {
        return (AVFormatContext)super.position(position);
}
```

I've tried to run a java application with an FFMmpegFrameGrabber while trying to run on windows. However same jar file runs on linux with no exceptions.

I have included javacpp and javacv jars .

However while running on windows I am getting this error 
**main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil"**

Stacktrace of exception

> 

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:
2719)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber
.java:391)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:
385)
        at testffmpeg.NewStreamer.StartandRestart(NewStreamer.java:191)
        at testffmpeg.NewStreamer.<init>(NewStreamer.java:95)
        at testffmpeg.NewStreamer.main(NewStreamer.java:91)
```

Comment: Weird. Could you show us your code that uses it?

Comment: Yes i have updated the code

Comment: Could you also paste the full stacktrace of your exception, formatted as code?

Comment: updated the stacktrace . please check